# Problems saving cookies when making HTTP requests using Python

Tags: python, post, web-crawler

I‘m trying to make a web-spider using python but I've got some problems when I tried to login the web site Pixiv.My code is as below:

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

url="https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php"

cookiename='123.txt'
cookie = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(cookiename)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
cookie.save()

values={'model':'login',
        'return_to':'/',
        'pixiv_id':'username',
        'pass':'password',
        'skip':'1'}

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'User-Agent' }
data=urllib.urlencode(values)
req=urllib2.Request(url,data)
response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page=response.read()
cookie.save()
```

To make sure it works, I used the cookielib to save the cookie as a txt file.I ran the code and got a "cookie.txt",but when I open the file I found that it was rmpty,in another word,my code didn't work.
I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your sample doesn't demonstrate your actual use of `cookielib`.  Please post a *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've edit  the code.I just used `cookie=cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(cookiename)`and`cookie.save()` to save the cookie file and got a empty one.But when I POSTed the same data by POSTMAN,it ran well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not using the `opener` that you created with the cookiejar attached to it in order to make the request.  `urllib2.urlopen` has no way of knowing that you want to use that opener to start the request.

You can either use the opener's [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.OpenerDirector.open) method directly or, if you want to use this by default for the rest of your application, you can install it as the default opener for all requests made with `urllib2` using [`urllib2.install_opener`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.install_opener).  So give that a try and see if it does the trick.